# There is a fatal error (for navigationbar) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am a new programmer. I have a problem about navigation controller. There was an error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value

**My Navigation Codes (there is an error):**

```
let color: UIColor = UIColor(red: 24.0 / 255, green: 75.0 / 255, blue: 152.0 / 255, alpha: 1)
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = color
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = .BlackTranslucent
```

Also I uploaded screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: does your view controller have navigation controller ?

Comment: Is your scene embedded in a `navigationController`? That's the only thing I see in your code that could be nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that, your navigation controller is nil. It means, your view controller didn't have any navigation controller attached to it.

You can either add a navigation controller programmatically or simply, you can go to `editor-> embed in -> navigation controller` in your Xcode

**Note:**

If you are presenting the view controller by code, make sure you present the view controller with navigation controller.

so, in your case,this code presents the Home view controller without the navigation controller.So even though your storyboard has the navigation controller, it will be nil, as you are presenting the HomeView controller only through code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC")
 self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

must be:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVCNavigation") //storyboard ID for the navigation controller HomeVCNavigation
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

OR

Try this:

```
   let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC") as! ViewController

let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1) // Creating a navigation controller with VC1 at the root of the navigation stack.

self.presentViewController(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

You  must present the navigation controller, which already has the Home view controller in it.
Change your code at here:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Beat you by 15 seconds ;)

Comment: Double check the module name. Give the correct module name.

Comment: Viewcontroller module name or navigationcontroller module name? Which one?

Comment: I used this code for logged users: `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
                            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC")
                            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: you need to instantiate the navigation controller, instead of view controller

Comment: give the navigation controller storyboard ID, and instatiate it

Comment: I did give a name: HomeNavigation to my navigation controller. I also add the HomeNavigation.swift file. Then, I changed my codes like this: `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
                            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeNavigation")
                            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`  But still, there was an error.

Comment: no , i provide u another way , look at OR part in my answer

Comment: I did also your OR Part... `let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC")
                            
                            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1) // Creating a navigation controller with VC1 at the root of the navigation stack.
                            
                            self.presentViewController(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)`

Comment: where r u doing this ? in app delegate ?

Comment: No, I was doing this in LoginVC.swift

Comment: whatever you do, must be done before you present the HOmeVC. Can you show the code where you do this?

Comment: Demo user is: mail: test password:test

Comment: I am so sorry, I forget this code, because, there is one more in the bottom of codes... Thank you so so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Select the viewController from Interface Builder, then click `Editor\Embed In\Navigation Controller`. It appears you don't have your scene embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: I uploaded screenshot, my view has a navigation controller... http://i.stack.imgur.com/CY5NO.png